# Add external js in magento using requires-config.js

Tags: magento-2.0

I have created a custom module and added requires-config.js (app\code\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend).

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        test: 'https://example.com/test.js'
    }
}
```

};

After that I have deploy the static content, now I can see the external js has added in following location (pub\static_requirejs\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US),but still external js is not loaded in page source (using console). 
Still I need to add the js files in layout?

```
<head>
    <link src="https://example.com/test.js"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its good practise to put your js in **Modulename/view/frontend/web/js** folder rather than loading from url.

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "test": "Modulename/js/test"
        }
    }
};
```

Also you don't need to add .js extenstion in the require js file.
then check it will load

Please clear the cache and also do static content deploy